# In Electron App,app.quit()&&ap.exit(0) can not teminate the process,how to deal with this?

Tags: javascript, electron

**my computer is mac, `Cmd+Q`can not quit the electron app! why? What should I do?**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation of the method [app.exit(exitCode)](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appexitexitcode):

> All windows will be closed immediately without asking user and the before-quit and will-quit events will not be emitted.

So on On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar to stay active. Try the following or change the method `app.exit()` by `app.quit()`

```
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```